# How to provide initial data for client side javascript?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, vue.js, asp.net-core-mvc, vuejs2

I just wonder if there was a new way to provide an initial data (json) for client side processing? I'm using ASP.NET Core MVC and I try to avoid an initial ajax request for data.

Currently I can render the Model into a json data within my asp.net view:

```
<script>
  var serverData = @Json.Serialize(Model); //List<TextItem>
</script>
```

Then I can access that serverData in my client script (VueJs, .vue component file):

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in list">{{item.text}}</li>
  </ul>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data: function () {
      return {
       list: serverData
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Solution works fine but I don't really like to render raw data into the page source. Is there any more elegant way to provide an inital data without any additinal (ajax) request to the server?

**Edit:**

I found an article about the concept (it uses angular):
https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/03/25/bootstrapping-angularjs-applications-with-server-side-data-from-aspnet-mvc

Is it still the best way to pre-render data on server side?

Comment: try with a static file.json in the front end solution

Comment: But then I have to generate a file for every request per client which would have a very bad performance.

Comment: mmm sorry i don't undestand..the data inside the file..are dinamic or static?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to make.You have to fetch data somewhere - API, Firebase etc.Of course you can put them manullay c/p but that's not point

Comment: I'm rendering an ASP.NET Core MVC view page which contains a client side (vuejs) mvvm js which works on data. The usual way is fire a request to a server api for data after "document ready". It works fine. But I try to avoid this extra additional request by rendering the MVC view with initial data.

Comment: Then I'll say your solution is fine

Comment: Is it possible to somehow compress/decompress plain json text? Using BSON can be a smarter solution?

Comment: You could also implement server side rendring to make sure the initial request fires only 1 request and that all your data is loaded when the first response comes from the server. And example of how to set this up with ASP.NET Core MVC with VueJs can be seen here: http://mgyongyosi.com/2016/Vuejs-server-side-rendering-with-aspnet-core/

Comment: And you can't achieve this by using vue props?

Comment: I don't want to influence the server side code with any particular client side library (vuejs for now) because it must be always replacable - so I won't use SSR ever. Currently I can put the initial data into the response html and I also successfully put bson string instead of plain json. Now I looking for a client side lib which can decode that binary string. Unfortunatelly bson npm lib uses different format than newtonsoft.